# What gem combinations should I use for testing my rails project?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, testing

Hi I usually use `cucumber`+`webrat`+`rspec/shoula`+`factory_girl` for tests. What gems should be added or replaced to make testing easier/better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use only rspec and factory_girl for testing - and it is pretty easy. And it is enough for me. As for me using to much testing frameworks is not good - it is very complicated and could brign strange behaviour.